# For image in Windows phone8 set frame

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new in windows phone 8 developer, I want to set position of image dynamically but I am not able to get any help I tried  img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(20.0, 30.0); but not working please tell me how can I get this functionality.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your image control in a Canvas element, like this:

```
<Canvas>
  <Image Name="ImgCtrl" Width="400" Height="400" Stretch="Uniform"
         Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"
         Source="image.jpg"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then you can change the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties programmatically in the code-behind, like this:

```
ImgCtrl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50.0);
ImgCtrl.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 50.0);
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/6084763 please see my actual problem I have mentioned comment for functionality that I have to achieve with code also.

Comment: please see it if u have solution for it then please give me some hint for that

Comment: please see my another problem and suggest me if u have any idea for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873226/capture-a-video-for-screen-activity-in-windows-phone-8